# Running into 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space' when using toPandas() and databricks connect

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, databricks, databricks-connect

I'm trying to transform a pyspark dataframe of size [2734984 rows x 11 columns] to a pandas dataframe calling `toPandas()`. Whereas it is working totally fine (11 seconds) when using an Azure Databricks Notebook, I run into a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exception when i run the exact same code using databricks-connect (db-connect version and Databricks Runtime Version match and are both 7.1).

I already increased the spark driver memory (100g) and the maxResultSize (15g). I suppose that the error lies somewhere in databricks-connect because I cannot replicate it using the Notebooks.

Any hint what's going on here?

The error is the following one:

````
Exception in thread "serve-Arrow" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.ning.compress.lzf.ChunkDecoder.decode(ChunkDecoder.java:51)
    at com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFDecoder.decode(LZFDecoder.java:102)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCClient.executeRPC0(SparkServiceRPCClient.scala:84)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.withRpcRetries(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:234)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.executeRPC(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:156)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.executeRPCHandleCancels(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:287)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.$anonfun$execute0$1(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:118)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner$$Lambda$934/2145652039.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.withRetry(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:135)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.execute0(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:113)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:86)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner$$Lambda$1031/465320026.apply(Unknown Source)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.Log4jUsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:210)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:346)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:325)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCClientStub.recordOperation(SparkServiceRPCClientStub.scala:61)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.execute(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:78)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.execute$(SparkServiceRemoteFuncRunner.scala:67)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCClientStub.execute(SparkServiceRPCClientStub.scala:61)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkServiceRPCClientStub.executeRDD(SparkServiceRPCClientStub.scala:225)
    at com.databricks.service.SparkClient$.executeRDD(SparkClient.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkClientContext$.executeRDD(SparkClientContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitJob(DAGScheduler.scala:864)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:928)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2331)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$6(Dataset.scala:3638)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$Lambda$3567/1086808304.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectAsArrowToPython$3(Dataset.scala:3642)```
````

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is likely because Databricks-connect is executing the toPandas on the client machine which can then run out of memory. You could increase the local driver memory by setting `spark.driver.memory` in the (local) config file `${spark_home}/conf/spark-defaults.conf` where `${spark_home}` can be obtained with `databricks-connect get-spark-home`.

Comment: Nice, it worked! I suspected something like this but was totally clueless where to start. For someone with the same problem: the ```\conf\spark-defaults.conf``` did not exist in my case to is just created it and inserted the following one liner: ```spark.driver.memory 10g```. I can know clearly see an increase in memory load on my local machine when running toPandas. Thanks again!